# Dual monitors - temporarily disable mouse travel

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse-cursor, aero-snap

I'm using Windows 7 with two monitors and sometimes move my mouse to the wrong screen accidentally. For example, I'm used to moving my mouse to the bottom left/bottom right corner to press start or "show desktop", but it often trails over to the next screen so I have to be precise. I also can't snap windows to the extended side of my main screen when two screens are active.

I like the idea of having two screens but it'd be nice if I could prevent moving the mouse over by default, and like, hold SHIFT to enable it or something. I'd only be using the second monitor to display documents and stuff that I just glance over.

Basically I want to use two monitors but have my mouse cursor act like I only have the one main one (adhering to the boundaries of main monitor), and to be able to toggle the ability to do things on the second one with a modifier.

Is it possible to have two extended displays but keep the mouse from travelling over in some cases? If the window "Snap" feature can be in tact that would also be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

First off set the left monitor as the main monitor, so you must move the mouse to the right to go to the extra monitor. Also snap will always work no matter how many windows you have, but you must utilize the keyboard commands (hold the windows key and press the arrow keys) to snap windows to the edges of the screens.